# How to put the below data in 3NF?

Tags: mysql, normalization

[image: Data that needs to be changed to 3NF]

I need to put the data from the diagram in 3NF (third normal form)

Comment: What does mysql have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table is for storing **Sales Record**, we can do the following:

For **1st Normal Form**:

- Eliminate columns with duplicate (not really eliminate but rather re-arrange).
  [image: 1st Normal Form]
- I just separated the columns with repeating data and made them new rows.

For **2nd Normal Form**

- The table should be in 1NF
- Remove subsets of data that apply to multiple rows of a table and place them in separate tables.
- Create relationships between these new tables and their predecessors through the use of foreign keys.
  [image: 2NF]
- Created new table for the **Seller**, **Customer**, **Product**, **Rating** and the **Records**.
- **Seller No.**, **Cust ID**, **Prod ID** and **Prod Rating** are their primary keys (which is foreign keys for **Sales Record Table**)

For **3rd Normal Form**

- The table should be in 2NF
- Remove columns that are not dependent upon the primary key.
  [image: 3NF]
- I usually encounter this form when dealing with addresses. As you can see i added the table **City** and used **Zip Code** as a foreign key.
- I also added a primary key in **Sales Record** table (**Record ID**).

You can read about normalization **[here](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)** and **[here](http://www.selikoff.net/2008/11/19/why-too-much-database-normalization-can-be-a-bad-thing/)**.

Last word:
Normalization is good for reducing data redundancy and ensuring that their relationships is used. Useful with JOINs but can be a headache when there is too much data and tables.